# How can I use Twitter Bootstrap in forms with Laravel 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I've added bootstrap css and js files to my laravel 4 layout.
How can I use it in the forms?
Is there any package or tutorial?
I found some old bundles but no composer packages...
Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: There are a few Laravel twitter bootrstrap packages: https://packagist.org/packages/patricktalmadge/bootstrapper for one

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I use twitter bootstrap from the CDN therefore no need to install packages. To use it in form, just pass the CSS class once calling the `FORM` helper.

A login example:

```
Form::open(['route' => 'login', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'clearfix'])    
Form::email('email', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email'))
Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password'))
Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'))
Form::close()
```

Comment: You could create macros that'd add Bootstrap-specific classes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Former](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former) is what you are looking for. It inherently capable of structurally creating form based on Twitter Bootstrap.

Example taken directly from the github page:

```
Former::horizontal_open()
  ->id('MyForm')
  ->secure()
  ->rules(['name' => 'required'])
  ->method('GET')

  Former::xlarge_text('name')
    ->class('myclass')
    ->value('Joseph')
    ->required();

  Former::textarea('comments')
    ->rows(10)->columns(20)
    ->autofocus();

  Former::actions()
    ->large_primary_submit('Submit')
    ->large_inverse_reset('Reset')

Former::close()
```